# Why display none for cypress is still visible?

Tags: javascript, cypress

I am testing my website using cypress, but there's one thing that confused me, is that when I using :

```css
display:none
```

And I use this line to test if the div still exist in the page:

```js
cy.get('[data-cy=searchBar]').should('not.exist')
```

It will still be detected as visible when testing, I think the reason is that I can still see the element inside the chrome dev tool, but I can't see it on the web page.

I know that I can simply use CSS attribute to check the display to finish my test, but I am wondering how this visible in cypress is designed, and why in this case it doesn't work?

[image]

Comment: I'm pretty sure `.should('not.exist')` means that the element doesn't exist at all in the DOM, not just that it's hidden. In this case the element is still there, it's just got a CSS property that hides it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`exist` and `visible` are two different assertions. **Exist** checks whether the element is present in the DOM. **Visible** checks whether the element is visible on the DOM.

Now for your element where it has a property of `display: none`, this signifies that element is not visible but it does exists.

```js
cy.get('[data-cy=searchBar]').should('be.visible') //Fails
cy.get('[data-cy=searchBar]').should('exist') //Passes
```